Video formats that support writing in a rolling fashion?
Are there any video formats out there that support writing in a rolling fashion? e.g. if I have a mmap/file that is the size of a 3 seconds video (1920x1080) at 30fps, I want to write frames to it sequentially. When the buffer gets full, I'll start writing it from the beginning of the mmap/file (so the first few frames would be overwritten).
Currently I'm saving RAW video. I was wondering if there are any video containers/formats that support rolling writing like above
This is how I'm writing right now
if self.video_offset + self.video_frame_size > self.video_buffer_size:
    self.video_offset = 0  # Reset the offset
    self.video_mmap.seek(self.video_offset) # video offset = 10 frames, video_frame_size = all the frames             
    self.video_mmap.write(np.array(frame, dtype=np.uint8).tobytes())
    self.video_offset = (self.video_offset + self.video_frame_size) % self.video_buffer_size

But I'm wondering if some readymade solutions exist for what I want to do. One simple way to do this is to store the size right after offset_size number of frames are written and then while reading the mmap/file, just read them. Another would be to write the video size in another file and read it before reading the mmap
Thank you!

no, there are not. you need to write in segments (individual files containing a piece of video, preferably more than a single frame), then delete your segments as needed. a file system does the "rolling" thing then, by allocating and deallocating disk space. -- saving "raw" video is a terrible idea. it wastes space, requires enormous bandwidth.

Why you are Not Just give your frame Buffer to a thread an encode them as h264

Can you elaborate on what specifically your goal is?  I can't think of a situation where it's worth writing a video to disk if you're only going to keep it for three seconds anyway.  Better to just keep it in memory at that point.  Any any case, Matroska is pretty easy to work with, in that after you have your initialization data, you can fairly arbitrarily cut the stream on Cluster boundaries from that point on.
